# FLV duration from Class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class, video, duration

I have a class which load and play a flv video file. My problem is, How can I get the flv`s duration in my main code? .. 
This is my video class:

```
package src {     
    import flash.display.Sprite;     
    import flash.media.Video;     
    import flash.net.NetConnection;     
    import flash.net.NetStream;      
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

        public class vplayer extends Sprite{                 
            public var vid:Video = new Video(1920,1080);
            private var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
            public var ns:NetStream;
            public var listener:Object = new Object();

            public function vplayer():void{             
                addChild(vid);
                nc.connect(null);
                ns = new NetStream(nc);
                vid.attachNetStream(ns);
                listener.onMetaData = metaDataHandler;
                ns.client = listener;           
                //customClient.onCuePoint = cuePointHandler;
            }
            public var time00:Number = 0;
            public function playVideo00():void{
                ns.play("image00/mov00.flv");
            }
            public function stopVideo00():void{
                ns.close();
            }
            /*public function cuePointHandler(infoObject:Object):void {
                trace("cuePoint");
            }*/
            public function metaDataHandler(infoObject:Object):void {
                trace (" Time:  " + infoObject["duration"]);
            }
        } 
}
```

.. and in my main class I have:

```
        Veed = new vplayer();
        addChild(Veed);
        Veed.playVideo00();
```

After running program I have " Time:  6.76" in output windows and it plays flv fine, which is correct but I want something like
`var myTD:int = Veed.getDuration();`
 in my main class to get the duration. It seems easy but I cannot make it done yet!! Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a private var at the top:

```
private var _duration:Number = 0;
```

Update this like so:

```
public function metaDataHandler(infoObject:Object):void
{
    _duration = infoObject["duration"];
}
```

Now create a getter for duration.

```
public function get duration():Number
{
    return _duration;
}
```

Now you can do a:

```
trace(Veed.duration);
```

---

The meta data will be retrieved even milliseconds after it's requested, meaning if you try fetch the duration immediately after fetching the meta data, it wouldn't have loaded yet. Try this as an example:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _wait);
function _wait(e:Event):void
{
    if(Veed.duration != 0)
    {
        trace(Veed.duration);
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _wait);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think because metaDataHandler is called asynchronously (not immediately). This is because the meta data needs to be retrieved first. Try adding a timer and see if it works? I'll show you an example.

Comment: YES, IT WORKS .. : ) ,, but is there any better way for this important proprty of FLV files? I was lucky because I already have one `addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainLoop);` in my code ..